# How to use Java 8 Optional feature on lower API level in android

Tags: android, java-8, option-type

We have an application that works with our BLE supported hardware which requires a minimum level of API 18. We need to use Optional feature of java 8 but they have reported that minimum level you have to maintain for such feature is API level 24 but we have to keep API level 18 for our hardware support. Though there are other third parties libs to have such feature , we want to use the official feature. Any way to gif rid of this or we have found an article that mentioned you have to write your own Optional class to have such a feature. So any good idea to get rid of this or to write our own as suggested by the article. Doing so can we violate the Oracle Copyright.

Comment: "we want to use the official feature" - there is a [guide](https://hivemq.github.io/hivemq-mqtt-client/docs/installation/android.html) on using the HiveMQ MQTT client (which uses some of the Java 8 API) on Android API level 19. AFAIU, it does some bytecode rewriting employing [Android RetroFix gradle plugin](https://github.com/SgtSilvio/android-retrofix). Could be of interest for you (disclaimer: I've never tried it myself).

Comment: @Sartorius thank you for your time. will look into it.